# Handle exception from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, exception

I have DLL written in C, which can raise a null-pointer exception. The DLL is used from C++ code. How can I handle this exception from C++ code?

Comment: How can a DLL written in C cause an exception to be thrown? Wouldn't it rather lead to a SIGSEGFAULT signal (or the analog on windows)?

Comment: __asm {
  mov eax, 0x00
  call eax;
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Structured Exception Handling (SEH). This is the Windows-specific way of catching various exceptions- `__try` and `__except`.